# Jenkins Job with SFDX command doesn't deploy the code and doesn't give an error

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, jenkins, cicd

SFDX Version: sfdx-cli/7.84.2-a2868a68d5 win32-x64 node-v12.18.3

Jenkins Job has 3 steps.

**Step1:** Pull the project from Git

**Step2:** Authentication

D:\project\jobname>sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid 3MVG9eYfd1zvW1E4hjmMNPbbByitZpubyv1izkalGFak_XXXXXXXX.4Y544bBqPpiBqc7mKchyCd3_ --username  jenkins.integration@XXX.COM --jwtkeyfile ../../JWT/server.key --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultdevhubusername

Successfully authorized jenkins.integration@XXX.COM with org ID 00D1b00000096eiQAB

**Step3:** Deploy
D:\project\jobname>sfdx force:source:deploy -c -u  jenkins.integration@XXX.COM --sourcepath Build/release/tmp/force-app --loglevel DEBUG

There is no error or success message. The deploy command doesn't error out or mention the components deployed. I know for a fact that the deployment did not happen as there no new entry in the sandbox deployment status section.

I checked the folder C:\Windows\TEMP folder for the sdx_sourceDeploy_pkg_1611581321557.zip file (number part is dynamic) while the job was running and it didn't generate one.
Source path Build/release/tmp/force-app has the code that I am planning to deploy.

Does this need any special permission for SFDX to generate the source zip file in TEMP or anyone other recommendation?

Comment: I take it you have a single dev org in use here, rather than creating a scratch org for each CI execution?

Comment: thats correct. It dev org and not scratch org

Answer (score 0):

Finally downgrading the SFDX version fixed my issue. I had to uninstall SFDX and install an older version.

SFDX Version: sfdx-cli/7.63.0-c897e8bb1a win32-x64 node-v10.20.1